# terminal hangs on "Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y"

Tags: 12.10, command-line

I am running an install on Ubuntu 12.10.  In the terminal I enter:

```
gksudo apt-get install <package>
```

I am then prompted:

```
After this operation, 4,789 kB of addition disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

I answer:

```
Y
```

terminal then appears to hang.  I have waited more than 10 minutes.

Please advise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As this was apparently the solution, I'm turning my comment into a full answer:

You used `gksudo` in your command. This is the *graphical* frontend for `sudo`. Using it in conjunction with a terminal-based program like `apt` is not only pointless, but can cause all sorts of fancy fun.

You would use `gksudo` to run a *graphical* program (like, say, `nautilus`), but `sudo` for commandline operations.

The correct command for your case would therefore be:

```
sudo apt-get install <package>
```

This should no longer cause it to get stuck.